# Dapper: "Insufficient parameters supplied to the command"

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

I have a `Test` model class:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public string One;
    public int Two;
}
```

I have a `test` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "test" 
(
    "one"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "two"   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

When trying to execute this code:

```cs
using (IDbConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (@One, @Two)", new Test
    {
        One = "hello",
        Two = 123
    });
}
```

I am getting this error:

> code = Unknown (-1), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): unknown error
>   Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

I tried everything and couldn't find why.

Comment: In order for Test class to be used One and Two must be properties, not fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper) requires command parameters as "Anonymous", "string", "List" and "dynamic"  for .execute() command, thus passing typed object is not supported

```
using (IDbConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Execute("INSERT INTO test (one, two) VALUES (@One, @Two)", new 
    {
        One = "hello",
        Two = 123
    });
}
```

**using your test object.**

```
using (IDbConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString))
{
    Test tobj = new Test();
    tobj.One = "hello";
    tobj.Two = 123;

    con.Execute("INSERT INTO test (one, two) VALUES (@One, @Two)", tobj);
}
```

Comment: I tried this already and just tried again. Same exception occurs.

Comment: i removed class "test", since we are building parameters. then give it a try

Comment: This do work, thanks a lot! However, how would I be able to pass a ``Test`` model as method parameter and use it for my query?

Comment: maybe its an array object

Comment: See 2:00 for his ``PersonModel``, it looks the same as mine, doesn't it?

Comment: yup, i got it, weird though, try this 2nd query.

Comment: Extremely weird .. I'd really like to avoid having to create a new object, this look like too complex when it can be way simplier .. I even tried using the exact same Dapper version as in this guy's video, it doesn't fix it .. I don't get it ...

Comment: yea, +1 on your question, really bugged my head in a while

Comment: Passing a ``Test`` model to it isn't working. However, an object such as ``object tobj = new { One = "hello", Two = 123 };`` do work.

Comment: https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper, only anonymous, list, string, dynamic parameters only supported.

Comment: Ahh well that's clearer! Thanks. Even if I still can't understand how is Tim Corey able to do it then .. What would be the easier way to convert my model to an anonymous type / object?

Comment: @Laiteux Tim Corey's class uses properties, not fields.

Answer (score 1):

Dapper doesn't know how to break down your class into two variables. See https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/540.
You can either use 1 parameter in your Insert statement and pass the class in, or 2 parameters and pass individual params as below.

```
        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("One", Test.One, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
        parameters.Add("Two", Test.Two, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);

        using (IDbConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (@One, @Two)", parameters);
        }
```

Comment: How would I pass the class to it, in an easy way?